# Array.prototype.sort() working on some cases and others not

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to sort an array of clothes sizes.

I used the `Array.prototype.sort()` function defininig an array of sizes and then sorting the input array following the order defined by me in the array
this works with standard sizes like **S, M and L** but doesn't with sizes like **40, 42, 44** etc.

**code sorting the array**

```
if (inputArray['code'] == 'size'){
            inputArray.sizes.sort(function(a,b) {
                var sizes = ["29","30","31","32","33","34","35","36","37","38","39","40","41","42",
                    "44","46","48","50","52","54","56","58","60",
                    "NT","N-USE",                  "2-3","3-4","4-5","5-6","6-7","7-8","8-9","9-10","10-11","10-13","11-13",
                    "XXXS","XXS","XX/XS","XS","XS/S","S","S/M","M","M/L","L","L/XL","XL","XL/XX","XXL","XXXL"];
                var optionValueA = a['label'];
                var optionValueB = b['label'];
                html += ' index position ' + optionValueA + '=' + sizes.indexOf(optionValueA) + ' ' + optionValueB + '=' + sizes.indexOf(optionValueB);
                return sizes.indexOf(optionValueA)+1 - sizes.indexOf(optionValueB)+1
            });
        }
html += ' SIZES json= ' + JSON.stringify(inputArray.sizes);
```

here is the output with standard sizes (well sorted)

> index position S=41 M=43 index position M=43 XL=47 index position
>   XL=47 XXL=49 index position XXL=49 L=45 index position XL=47 L=45
>   index position M=43 L=45 SIZES json=
>   [{"id":"646","label":"S","products":["28535"]},{"id":"672","label":"M","products":["28536"]},{"id":"651","label":"L","products":["28539"]},{"id":"691","label":"XL","products":["28537"]},{"id":"640","label":"XXL","products":["28538"]}]

and here the output with numeric sizes (not well sorted)

> index position 42=13 44=14 index position 42=13 46=15 index position
>   46=15 48=16 index position 42=13 48=16 index position 46=15 50=17
>   index position 50=17 54=19 index position 54=19 52=18 index position
>   50=17 52=18 index position 46=15 52=18 SIZES json=
>   [{"id":"687","label":"44","products":["23300"]},{"id":"650","label":"42","products":["23299"]},{"id":"649","label":"48","products":["23302"]},{"id":"643","label":"46","products":["23301"]},{"id":"688","label":"52","products":["23305"]},{"id":"669","label":"50","products":["23303"]},{"id":"684","label":"54","products":["23304"]}]

here the **original arrays** (before sorting) from debug

numeric sizes

> ORIGINAL ARRAY=
>   [{"id":"650","label":"42","products":["23299"]},{"id":"687","label":"44","products":["23300"]},{"id":"643","label":"46","products":["23301"]},{"id":"649","label":"48","products":["23302"]},{"id":"669","label":"50","products":["23303"]},{"id":"684","label":"54","products":["23304"]},{"id":"688","label":"52","products":["23305"]}]

standard sizes

> ORIGINAL ARRAY=
>   [{"id":"646","label":"S","products":["28535"]},{"id":"672","label":"M","products":["28536"]},{"id":"691","label":"XL","products":["28537"]},{"id":"640","label":"XXL","products":["28538"]},{"id":"651","label":"L","products":["28539"]}]

im not very skilled in js so mabe someone can help
thanks in advance

Comment: please add your original array as well with some space, like from `JSON.stringify` and add the sort order for the same groups of size.

Comment: here you are

numeric sizes

Comment: What is the `+1 +1` doing there?

Comment: because js array indexes start from 0 but actually its useless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your comparison function is [inconsistent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24080786/1048572), in particular the part

```
return sizes.indexOf(optionValueA)+1 - sizes.indexOf(optionValueB)+1
//                                ^^                              ^^
```

If the two compared values are 2 or less indices apart and `a` should be smaller than `b`, the function returns the wrong result (`>0` instead of `<=0`). This will lead to the unexpected ordering.

I presume you meant

```
return (sizes.indexOf(optionValueA)+1) - (sizes.indexOf(optionValueB)+1)
```

but that's unnecessary and can be simplified to

```
return sizes.indexOf(optionValueA) - sizes.indexOf(optionValueB)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an object for the sort order and a default value if necessary.

The order is build with the item and an incremented index.

```js
function orderSize(a, b) {
    return (order[a.label] || 0) - (order[b.label] || 0);
}

var array1 = [{ "id": "640", "label": "XXL", "products": ["28538"] }, { "id": "646", "label": "S", "products": ["28535"] }, { "id": "672", "label": "M", "products": ["28536"] }, { "id": "651", "label": "L", "products": ["28539"] }, { "id": "691", "label": "XL", "products": ["28537"] }],
    array2 = [{ "id": "643", "label": "46", "products": ["23301"] }, { "id": "650", "label": "42", "products": ["23299"] }, { "id": "649", "label": "48", "products": ["23302"] }, { "id": "684", "label": "54", "products": ["23304"] }, { "id": "688", "label": "52", "products": ["23305"] }, { "id": "669", "label": "50", "products": ["23303"] }, { "id": "687", "label": "44", "products": ["23300"] }],
    sizes = ["29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "44", "46", "48", "50", "52", "54", "56", "58", "60", "NT", "N-USE", "2-3", "3-4", "4-5", "5-6", "6-7", "7-8", "8-9", "9-10", "10-11", "10-13", "11-13", "XXXS", "XXS", "XX/XS", "XS", "XS/S", "S", "S/M", "M", "M/L", "L", "L/XL", "XL", "XL/XX", "XXL", "XXXL"],
    order = {};

sizes.forEach(function (a, i) { order[a] = i + 1; });

array1.sort(orderSize);
array2.sort(orderSize);

console.log(array1);
console.log(array2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If you like to sort mixed sizes, you could use directly an object, with mapped sort values for various size systems, like

```
{
    64: 1,
    xs: 2,
    68: 3,
    72: 4
    s:  5
    76: 6
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: but i still cant figure out why the previous implementation didnt work with numeric sizes

Comment: got it by @Bergi comment

Comment: the reason is, you get the difference but you add 2 on the sorting result. you could group the return with parenthesis, to get the wanted result, like `(sizes.indexOf(optionValueA) + 1) - (sizes.indexOf(optionValueB)+1
)` or omit the addition with one.